# Azure App Service - write to filesystem - ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, file-io, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET web application, created in Visual Studio 2017.

In the application there is a form, where the users can upload files. When files are uploaded, I process them and I save them on the filesystem:

```
var photo = Request.Files["file"];
photo.SaveAs("D:\\home");
```

Everything works perfect locally, but it's not working when I deploy the App on Azure App Services.

I read that, on Azure, the path

```
D:\home
```

should be writable.

But when I try the code I get this error:

```
Access to the path 'd:\home\test_image.JPG' is denied.
```

Comment: `d:\home` probably doesn't (even) exist. Have a look at @sprinter252 's answer, or get the temp folder, or use storage.

Answer (score 11):

Use `%TEMP%`, which on Azure App Service (Windows) resolves to `d:\local`. That's the local machine disk, not network storage, so significantly faster. It gets wiped on app restart so code accordingly.

```cs
var tempDirectoryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
var filePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectoryPath, Request.Files["file"]);
```

If you want durability use Blob Storage instead.

Comment: Can we read file which is stored in this Temp folder? If yes, then how. Actually i want to show that uploaded file on web.

Comment: If you're talking about user uploads you should upload to Blob Storage not App Service temporary storage. Nothing is stopping you from reading content from temporary storage. You read it like you read any other file from disk in your code.

Comment: where to store data to persist them after a restart?

Comment: D:\HOME\ on Windows workers and /home/ for Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You should never use absolute paths on server components. Try something like this for instance

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, Request.Files["file"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!